# Is there any reason behind the spelling of "expresso" in French?

Tags: orthographe, emprunts

My understanding is that "espresso" is a word of Italian origin, but the French use the word "expresso" instead.  Is there any reason for the difference in spelling, as many other languages have adopted the Italian spelling?

Comment: Pour le café ?  For the coffee ?

Comment: espresso is also used in French, and if I believe my impression confirmed by [ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=expresso%2Cespresso&year_start=1800&year_end=2100&corpus=7&smoothing=3), more so that expresso.

Comment: Worth noting that, even in English, 'espresso' is *very* commonly mispronounced 'expresso', so the transformation comes quite naturally to people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voici ce que l'on trouve sous *expresso* dans le Petit Robert de la langue française en ligne (accès par abonnement) :

> expresso [ɛkspʀeso] nom masculin
>   étym. 1968 ◊ italien espresso avec influence de 2. express
>
> ❖ Café express. *« la machine à expressos dont l'eau sous pression s'échapperait »* (J. Almira). ➙ percolateur.

Regardons ce qui se trouve sous l'entrée *2. express* :

> 2- express [ɛkspʀɛs] adjectif et nom masculin
>   étym. 1957 ◊ de l'italien (caffè) espresso, d'après l'anglais
>
> ❖ 1.  *Café express*, fait à la vapeur, à l'aide d'un percolateur.
>
> ❖ 2.  N. m. plus cour. Café préparé de cette manière. ➙ expresso. *Boire deux express. Un express serré.*

Il semble qu'un "café express" ait été employé avant "expresso", ce qui ne semble avoir laissé aucune chance à la graphie italienne pour s'imposer, même s'il semble y avoir eu un effort.

Comment: Étrange, le [ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=expresso%2Cespresso&year_start=1800&year_end=2100&corpus=7&smoothing=3) donne un pic pour *expresso* dans les années **1840**, un pour *espresso* ver **1890** et *espresso* dominant *expresso* depuis les années 40. Tout bien avant 1957 ou 1968.

Comment: Étrange, en effet, qu'un siècle d'utilisation (d'*expresso*, au moins) n'est pas suffit à l'attestation étymologique. Je ne saurais dire, à la lumière de ce ngram, pourquoi *expresso* l'a emporté sur *espresso*.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Le corpus de Google n'est pas très bien classé, si tu suis les recherches associées sur `books` tu verras beaucoup de résultats en latin ou en italien qui faussent tout.

Comment: Les Italiens simplifient tout (comparer avec le latin …), les Français moins, restant plus fidèles à l'étymologie, comme les anglophones du reste (en l'occurrence, ces derniers choisissent la graphie italienne).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, according to [wikipedia:en](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Espresso#Etymology_and_usage_of_the_term), *expresso* is used in English, too.

Their notice is quite obivious, here it is.

> The origin of the term "espresso" is the subject of considerable debate. Although some Anglo-American dictionaries simply refer to "pressed-out", "espresso," much like the English word "express", conveys the senses of "just for you" and "quickly," which can be related to the method of espresso preparation.
>
> [...]
>
> Many Latin European countries, such as France, use the expresso form. In the United States and Canada, the spelling espresso is widely considered correct while expresso appears as a less common variant or misspelling. Italy uses the term espresso, substituting most x letters in Latin root words with s; x is not considered part of the standard Italian alphabet.

Comment: "Expresso" may be *used* in English, but as Wikipedia says, it's a misspelling. People who write it are generally people who don't realize that "espresso" is the canonical and original spelling. In any case, I'm not sure it explains the French spelling.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's an anglicism because we use the word "**express**".

Comment: Yes it might be a marketing thing to insist that it is "fast". "Express" comes from french "exprès" though.

Comment: An italanglicism ? An anglitalianism ?

Comment: Or it could be a throwback to the original Latin.

Answer (score -1):

De l’italien espresso (extrait par pression ou très vite, express) - http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/expresso

Comment: La question était justement pourquoi pas *espresso*.

Comment: Il sait que ça vient du mot Italien Espresso. Il veut savoir pourquoi les français ont remplacé le premier 's' par un 'x'.

Comment: Tout simplement parce qu'on a réuni le 'express' (très vite) au mot italien.  Ma réponse n'était pas claire.

Comment: @Nikko Je ne parle pas italien, mais je n'ai pas l'impression que *espresso* y ait quelque chose à voir avec la pression. C'est la même racine que *exprès* ou *express*, du latin *expressus*.

Comment: oui je ne parle pas italien non plus, il faudrait qu'un italien vienne nous aider. Peut-être qu'effectivement le mot italien convoie les deux sens. Ou juste "rapidement".